# Не работает слайдер с динамическим добавлением/удалением слайдов

Tags: javascript

Не работает слайдер с динамическим добавлением/удалением слайдов - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetLeft' of undefined.
Ошибка где-то тут:

```
_slide: function() {
        this.animate = 1;
        this.$slider.css('overflow', 'hidden');
        this.showAllTabs();
        this.$wrapper.css('left', this.$tabs[this.current_position].offsetLeft*-1); // смещение текущего слайда в px

        this.arrowAction();
        var self = this;
        var tmt = setTimeout(this.hideTabs.bind(self), 600);
    },
```

Полный код [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/238rm6so/)

**UPD html**

```
<div id="multiSelection" class="tabs-slider">
<ul class="tabs-slider-wrapper nav nav-tabs js_order_service_tabs">

    <? $active = 'active'; ?>

    <? foreach($this->getServicesTabsFromRequestServiceInfo() as $tab_id => $tab_title): ?>
          <li class="js_order_request_service_tab_<?=$tab_id;?>   js_order_request_service_tab <?=$active;?>"
            tabid="order_service_<?=$tab_id;?>">
            <a href="#order_service_<?=$tab_id;?>"
               data-toggle="tab"><?=$tab_title;?>
                <i class="icon icon-remove js_remove_service_tab"
                   data-order-service-tab-id="<?=$tab_id;?>"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
        <? if($active) $active = ''; ?>
    <? endforeach; ?>

    <li id="TabAdded" class="dropdown js_order_add_service_tab">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <i class="icon icon-plus"></i>&nbsp;Добавить услугу<b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu order-add-service-dropdown-menu">
            <? foreach($this->services as $code => $title): ?>
                <li><a data-service-id="<?=$code;?>" href="#"><?=$title;?></a></li>
            <? endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
<div class="border-bottom"></div>

<div class="tabs-slider-nav">
    <div id="moveTabsLeft" class="roller roller-wrap-style-left slider-previous">
        <i  class="icon icon-chevron-left icon-position-left "></i>
    </div>
    <div id="moveTabsRight" class="roller roller-wrap-style-right slider-   next">
        <i  class="icon icon-chevron-right icon-position-right"></i>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="request-service-tab-content tab-content">
<? $active = 'active'; ?>
<? foreach($this->getServicesTabsContentFromRequestServiceInfo() as $tab_id    => $tab_content): ?>
    <div class="order-service-tab tab-pane <?=$active;?>"
         id="order_service_<?=$tab_id;?>"><?=$tab_content;?></div>
    <? if($active) $active = ''; ?>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: очевидно `this.$tabs[this.current_position]` - `undefined`

Comment: в приведенном _полном_ коде нет html, следовательно он не сильно помогает в воспроизведении проблемы

Comment: Марина, как и в прошлом случае мы не можем удалить просто так вопрос, если на него уже дан ответ. Но я переоткрыл второй вопрос, на который нашлось решение.

Comment: @Grundy: может быть, вы на основе ответа к этому вопросу напишете ответ к другому вопросу Марины, а этот удалите?

Comment: спасибо) в идеале, лучше удалить этот вопрос, т.к. на него не может быть дан корректный ответ. ответ уже есть в другом похожем (НО не дублирующем) вопросе

Comment: отредактировала вопрос, добавила html

Answer (score 1):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetLeft' of undefined.

Данная ошибка говорит о том, что свойство *offsetLeft* пытаются взять у объекта, который `undefined`.

В данном случае это выражение

```
this.$tabs[this.current_position]
```

может возвращать `undefined` по нескольким причинам:

1. `this.current_position` не определен
2. `this.$tabs` - пустой массив(jQuery Объект)
3. в `this.$tabs` нет поля соответствующего `this.current_position`

Поэтому первое, что надо сделать: проверить значения этих переменных во время выполнения, либо с помощью отладки, либо выведя их используя `console.log`

```
console.log('current position', this.current_position, 'tabs', this.$tabs, 'element',this.$tabs[this.current_position]);
this.$wrapper.css('left', this.$tabs[this.current_position].offsetLeft*-1); // смещение текущего слайда в px
```

После этого уже можно смотреть дальше в конкретных направлениях.

Например, в лог вывелось, что `this.$tabs` - пустой, следовательно нужно проверить где заполняется это свойство.

В коде оно заполняется в двух местах

```
init: function(options) {
    ...
    this.$tabs = $('.js_order_service_tabs > li');
    ...
}
```

и

```
getTabsWidth: function() {
    this.$tabs = $('.js_order_service_tabs > li');
    ...
}
```

Так как больше в коде это свойство не изменяется - то нужно проверить есть ли в разметке элементы удовлетворяющие указанному селектору, а именно

```
<!-- предположим что это все таки список, хотя может быть любой элемент с указанным классом -->
<ul class="js_order_service_tabs">
    <li><li><!-- выбираются все дочерние элементы li, не выбирая те которые могут быть на более низком уровне вложенности -->
    <li> <!-- данный элемент выберется -->
        <ul>
            <li></li> <!-- Данные не выберется -->
            ...
        </ul>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Если элементы присутствуют, то проблема со счетчиком. Так как нигде не проверяются границы, а выполняется просто увеличение или уменьшение счетчика, то, вполне возможно, в какой-то момент его значение становится либо больше максимального индекса `this.$tabs`, либо меньше `0`.

Comment: спасибо за подробное разъяснение! проблема с `this.current_position` в какой-то момент он не правильно определяется

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, по предоставленному куску вряд ли можно что-то добавить. В принципе в последнем абзаце про проблему со счетчиком описано немного, возможно это как раз ваш случай